# Testing own self-made os with qemu. asm/c++

Tags: c++, assembly, operating-system, ld, qemu

I have made basic os, which doesn't really do anything yet, but I want to test it on qemu. But what I must do for the output file of ld-linker to get it work with qemu(iso, or something?).

This is my linker script:

```
OUTPUT_FORMAT("binary")
ENTRY(start)
SECTIONS
{
    .text 0x00100000:
    {
        code = .; _code = .; __code = .;
        *(.text)
        . = ALIGN(4096);
    }
    textEnd = .;

    .data :
    {
        data = .; _data = .; __data = .;
        *(.data)
        . = ALIGN(4096);
    }
    dataEnd = .;

    .bss :
    {
        bss = .; _bss = .; __bss = .;
        *(.bss)
        . = ALIGN(4096);
    }
    bssEnd = .;

    end = .; _end = .; __end = .;
}
```

boot.s: (ASM)

```
[BITS 32]

MBOOT_PAGE_ALIGN    equ 1 << 0
MBOOT_MEM_INFO      equ 1 << 1
MBOOT_AOUT_KLUDGE   equ 1 << 16
MBOOT_MAGIC equ 0x1BADB002
MBOOT_FLAGS equ MBOOT_PAGE_ALIGN | MBOOT_MEM_INFO | MBOOT_AOUT_KLUDGE
CHECKSUM    equ -(MBOOT_MAGIC + MBOOT_FLAGS)
STACK_SIZE  equ 0x1000

[global start]
[extern main]
[extern textEnd]
[extern dataEnd]
[extern bssEnd]

entry:
    jmp start

align 4, db 0
mBootHeader:
    dd MBOOT_MAGIC
    dd MBOOT_FLAGS
    dd CHECKSUM
    dd mBootHeader
    dd entry
    dd dataEnd
    dd bssEnd
    dd entry

start:
    call main
    cli
    hlt
```

I compiled whole thing as follows:

```
$ nasm -f aout boot.s -o boot.o
$ gcc -c kernel.cpp -ffreestanding -nostdlib -fno-builtin -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions -m32
$ ld -T link.ld -o kernel.bin boot.o kernel.o -melf_i386
```

This all work with no errors, only problem is how I boot it in qemu?
Output file is executable, but of course I can't run it on linux because it's an operating-system.

Comment: If the `boot.asm` is a bootloader (with the correct signature) then using the binary file as a disk-image should be enough.

Comment: Also, I recommend reading the tutorials [on this wiki](http://wiki.osdev.org/Expanded_Main_Page), and possibly [these tutorials](http://www.osdever.net/tutorials/) as well.

Comment: Ok, it can boot now, but in qemu it boots grub again when I hit enter. On real hardware it boots to grub, but then happens nothing.

Comment: you may get help  here http://www.bravegnu.org/gnu-eprog/index.html

Answer (score 0):

If you have qemu you can start it using:

`qemu-system-i386 -kernel kernel.bin`

Comment: This doesn't work in this case, it fills terminal with "pflash_write: Unimplemented flash cmd sequence (offset 0000000000000040, wcycle 0x0 cmd 0x0 value 0x100079)", and freezes. That's bug on qemu.